# Two Black Holes held stationary by EM forces

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, charge, event-horizon

If two black holes with large enough mass (so that the tidal forces are minimal and the intersection is large) that are held apart by like charges (saddle point stability). Imagine the black holes in a vacuum placed such that there event horizons are overlapping. Is this overlapping space transversable? Why not if the answer is no?

Comment: If the horizons meet, it's not two black holes, anymore.

Comment: I highly doubt that this situation is realisable, or stable.

Answer (score 1):

If the event horizons overlap you get one big horizon. EM forces can not counteract gravity if the curvature is too large since the force required to counteract gravity becomes infinite at the horizon. You can see this in the equation

$$F=\frac{G\cdot M\cdot m}{r^2\cdot\sqrt{1-r_s/r}} $$

which becomes infinite at the horizon $r_s$. Since from the outside perspective everthing that fell into the black hole got stuck on the horizon because of time dilation, the matter that makes up the black hole is layered [outside](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMRYZMv0jRE&t=34m20s) the horizon, so if both horizons would touch, the two black holes would have to merge.

Also see http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0411060v2.pdf:

> "For a Schwarzschild (non-rotating, uncharged) black hole, the river falls radially inward at the Newtonian escape velocity, hitting the speed of light at the horizon. Inside horizons, the river of space moves faster than light, carrying everything with it."

In other words, you can't hold two black holes stationary if their horizons overlap.

Comment: Space does not "flow in" to a mass and electric field does not "flow out" of a charge. Changes in both gravitational and electric fields propagate at $c$ but that has nothing to do with the forces mediated by the field in the static case.

Answer (score 1):

Traversable - Overlapping (actually intersecting) region would not be Traversable even if the gravity at some parts of the region may be zero. For exampple, between earth and moon, gravity will be zero at some point. That does not mean something in that region can go out of earth/moon system. As soon as an observer leaves that region, it either falls towards moon, or towards earth, or towards that region.
Same thing would apply in case of two black holes but with extreme forces/speeds.

If you mean "intersecting" when you say "overlapping", then - overlapping  EH does not necessarily mean a single black hole. EH is nothing physical, it is just a region of space around singularity.

Suppose, both the black holes can, each hold necessary amount of charge, and suppose the charge does not abandon its normal property when fallen into a singularity, then it should be possible for EM forces to counter gravity, even if their EH are intersecting, but the singularities have to be outside the EH of one another.

Intersection of event horizons would not cause faster than c condition for the singularities. Faster than c would be caused only when something physically enters event horizon. Two event horizons are not physical, singularities are physical which are still outside each other's event horizons.

Comment: Wouldn't we be able to walk on the line of zero gravity caused by the symmetries and leave? Does this system act as if there was a "black hole" pulling you into the center of the section? And is this avoidable by having larger black holes making net forces weaker?

Comment: shaihorowitz:  Theoretically, should be possible to walk inside the intersected region, but when you try to leave that region, then you either fall into one of the black holes, or back into that region as if you were trying to leave a combined black hole. The EH of combined mass would be larger than sum of individuals and would fully contain individual event horizons. So, an exit seems impossible.